# Hibernate adding new element @oneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

what's wrong guys I have that relations in hibernate `@oneToMany`:

This is in loan class:

`@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private users user;`

This is in user class:
    `@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<loans> loans=new HashSet<loans>(0);`

here I have method to insert new loan:

```
public static void addLoanToUser(Integer userID,String brand,String model,String registration,String loanStart , String loanEnd){
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      Transaction transaction = null;
    try {   

        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                    users user = (users) session.load(users.class, userID);
                    Set<loans> loanSet = new HashSet();

                    loans loan = new loans();                        
                    loan.setBrand(brand);
                    loan.setModel(model);
                    loan.setRegistration(registration);
                    loan.setLoanStart(loanStart);
                    loan.setLoanEnd(loanEnd);
                    loan.setPaydone("no");
                    loanSet.add(loan);
                    user.setLoans(loanSet);

                    session.saveOrUpdate(user);
                    session.save(loan);

        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

 }
```

When I insert data to the database there is always NULL on Foreign Key.
I tried to find sth on the stack but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have to set relation on "key holder" in your case that is `loan` entity. So

```
users user = (users) session.load(users.class, userID);
loans loan = new loans();  
..... setup
loan.setUser(user)
session.saveOrUpdate(user);
```

And you do realize, that if user will take new loan, you effectively removes other loans of that user (in current session) by setting brand new `user.loans` set ? :) I wish banking systems work like that :)

Comment: wow ! I didn't realize that . Is there other way to resolve it ?

Comment: But what? Original question? As I specify above - the load. The funny issue? `Set<loans> loanSet = user.getLoans()`